# User's null-terminated input

Tags: c++

just a quick question. I'm looking for the most efficient and clear way to get the user's input of any length and store it, so then I can retrieve it and compare to another input. I also need the user's input to be null-terminated. Can I write something like

```
string inp;
cin >> inp;
```

Comment: define "most efficient"?

Comment: If you string has spaces in it then you will need to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: by the most efficient I mean an already null-terminated input. Is a string-object gonna be null-terminated if I ask for a user's input, or I will have to add '\0' manually?

Comment: As @NathanOliver says, use `std::getline` and then use `str.c_str()` to obtain a NULL-terminated string.

Comment: @trollpidor Why do you care about null-termination? Functions working with `string` operate on the length of the string instead of a delimiter at the end (and that can sometimes improve efficiency, and almost always improves safety). Are you working with a C API afterwards? If so, the `c_str()` method as pointed out should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) will manage itself and grow to accommodate the input that is given to the program.  If you have

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

This will get input from the user that includes spaces that can be as big as the input stream can hold.  Now that you have the string if you need to pass it to some function that needs an old null terminated c-style string then you would use the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function.  `c_str()` does return a `const char *` so you will not be able to modify the string data with it.

If you really need a modifyable c-style string then you can make one with

```
char * old_style_string = new char[input.size() + 1];
std::strcpy(old_style_string, input.c_str());
```

Comment: got it, I was kinda confused because I though for some reason that c++ string is also null-terminated, like a c string. But it's basically a vector with a bit different functionality. Thanks

Comment: @trollpidor Basically.  If you just deal with `std::string`s you don't need to worry about a NULL terminator.